# PHP - sum one or more values with the same key

Tags: php, arrays

What is the best way to sum the 'val','val1','val2' field with the same 'color' for each different color:

I have the below array format. Add the key values in that array if the color have same values. Please help me out. Thanks in advance

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [color]=> "red"
            [val]=> 4
            [val1]=> 4
            [val2]=> 4
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [color]=> "green"
            [val]=> 3
            [val1]=> 3
            [val2]=> 3
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [color]=> "blue"
            [val]=> 1
            [val1]=> 3
            [val2]=> 3
        )    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [color]=> "green"
            [val]=> 6
            [val1]=> 3
            [val2]=> 3
        )    
    [4] => Array
        (
            [color]=> "blue"
            [val]=> 2
            [val1]=> 3
            [val2]=> 3
        )
)
```

**My Desired result :**

```
 (
        [color] => red
        [val] => 4
        [val1] => 4
        [val2] => 4
        
    )
    (
        [color] => green
        [val] => 9
        [val1] => 6
        [val2] => 6
        
    )
    (
        [color] => blue
        [val] => 3
        [val1] => 6
        [val2] => 6
        
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreach over the array and use color as key.

```
$array = [
    [
        'color' => "red",
        'val'   => 4,
        'val1'  => 4,
        'val2'  => 4,
    ],
    [
        'color' => "green",
        'val'   => 3,
        'val1'  => 3,
        'val2'  => 3,
    ],
    [
        'color' => "blue",
        'val'   => 1,
        'val1'  => 3,
        'val2'  => 3,
    ],
    [
        'color' => "green",
        'val'   => 6,
        'val1'  => 3,
        'val2'  => 3,
    ],
    [
        'color' => "blue",
        'val'   => 2,
        'val1'  => 3,
        'val2'  => 3,
    ],
];

$colors = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    foreach (['val', 'val1', 'val2'] as $key) {
        $colors[$item['color']][$key] = ($colors[$item['color']][$key] ?? 0) + $item[$key];
    }
}

print_r($colors);
```

will result in

```
Array
(
    [red] => Array
        (
            [val] => 4
            [val1] => 4
            [val2] => 4
        )

    [green] => Array
        (
            [val] => 9
            [val1] => 6
            [val2] => 6
        )

    [blue] => Array
        (
            [val] => 3
            [val1] => 6
            [val2] => 6
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with `Foreach` loop and do the adding calculation within the loop.

```
$baseArray = [
    [
        'color' => "red",
        'val'   => 4,
        'val1'  => 4,
        'val2'  => 4,
    ],
    [
        'color' => "green",
        'val'   => 3,
        'val1'  => 3,
        'val2'  => 3,
    ],
    [
        'color' => "blue",
        'val'   => 1,
        'val1'  => 3,
        'val2'  => 3,
    ],
    [
        'color' => "green",
        'val'   => 6,
        'val1'  => 3,
        'val2'  => 3,
    ],
    [
        'color' => "blue",
        'val'   => 2,
        'val1'  => 3,
        'val2'  => 3,
    ],
];

$colorsArray = [];
$arrayKeys = ['val', 'val1', 'val2'];

foreach ($baseArray as $item) {
    foreach ($arrayKeys as $keyName) {
        $colorsArray[$item['color']]['color'] = $item['color'];
        $colorsArray[$item['color']][$keyName] = ($colorsArray[$item['color']][$keyName] ?? 0) + $item[$keyName];
    }
}

$colorsArray = array_values($colorsArray);

print_r($colorsArray);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [color] => red
            [val] => 4
            [val1] => 4
            [val2] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [color] => green
            [val] => 9
            [val1] => 6
            [val2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [color] => blue
            [val] => 3
            [val1] => 6
            [val2] => 6
        )
)
```